No Upload to Sharepoint via macro
I have a small problem with a macro that is currently driving me to despair.
The macro is supposed to save files to a specific location.
The marko reads the value from cell A2 and then saves the corresponding .txt file. The name of the file is the value from cell a2.
The files are saved once on a company-internal server drive, and then additionally uploaded to two sharepoint folders. One folder is assigned to a team and the other to the private user folder.
The macro works for me so far. For a colleague who runs the same macro, the file is only saved on the local server and on the folder assigned to a team. (1st & 2nd line with the command "ActiveWorkbook.save as")
The third line is not executed. However, there is no error message when executing the code. If we try to save the file on the hard disk C, this is also not executed by my colleague.
Can someone help us and explain where the error is?
Thanks in advance.
Following is the code snippet:
fileExtension = Right(wk.FullName, Len(wk.FullName) - InStrRev(wk.FullName, "."))
    wk.Activate
    
    If wk.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        
        If fileExtension = "txt" Then    
        
            If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
                    y = Range("a2").Value
                    Dateiname = Trim(Mid(y, 24, 120))
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="G:\yxy\1 yyy\Dashboard\Datengrundlage\" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://yyyyroup.sharepoint.com/sites/SOyyyy-S_OP/Shared Documents/S_OP/Fertigungskonzept\" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://yyygroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yyy/Documents/yyy/" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    
                    
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Else
                    y = Range("A3").Value
                    Dateiname = Trim(Mid(y, 30, 120))
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="G:\yxy\1 yyy\Dashboard\Datengrundlage\" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://yyyyroup.sharepoint.com/sites/SOyyyy-S_OP/Shared Documents/S_OP/Fertigungskonzept\" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="https://yyygroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/yyy/Documents/yyy/" & Dateiname, Local:=True
                    
                    
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close
            
               End If
        Else


Chaning the code, trying to save to an other folder

Is there an ownership conflict?

Have you tried defining type of file to be saved? It does not work without that for me. Like:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="G:\yxy\1 yyy\Dashboard\Datengrundlage" & Dateiname, Local:=True, FileFormat:=51
It is optional, however I found out that saveas method on sharepoint often does not work without that.

"If we try to save the file on the hard disk C, this is also not executed by my colleague" - maybe start with this problem, since it doesn't seem Sharepoint-specific. Can you post a full code only reproduces just the failure to save to the C drive?   Should only need a few lines of code for that.

Hey, everyone. Thanks for your fast replies and your suggestions to solve the problem.
